# Cannot use ACL to give user write permissions, is ACL enabled?

Tags: linux, rhel, acl

On a RedHat 6.9 server I have a folder named "/Data", permissions are:

```
drwxrwxr-x   20 root root 4.0K Apr 24  2018 Data
```

I want to add a user via ACL to have write permission on this folder for current files and any new files created, so I tried this:

```
setfacl -d -R -m "u:NewUser:rwX," /Data/
```

However I get permission denied when I try and create or edit a file.

The output of

```
mount -l | grep Data
```

shows:

```
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-Data_Vol on /Data type ext4 (rw,acl)
```

Output of:

```
tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-Data_Vol | grep options
```

shows:

```
Default mount options:    (none)
```

So I ran:

```
tune2fs -o acl /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-Data_Vol
```

Now output of:

```
tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-Data_Vol | grep options
```

is:

```
Default mount options:    acl
```

But I still can't get the ACl to work.

Is there anything I have missed or any other steps I can try to make this work?

Comment: Just try setfacl -d -R -m u:NewUser:rwx /Data

Comment: have you umount/mount after tune2fs ?

Comment: Yes, tried to remount but same problem, command I used was "mount -o remount -o acl /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-Data_Vol  /Data"

Comment: Also tried to use "setfacl -d -R -m u:NewUser:rwx /Data" but still get permission denied